# Can every "not-too-big" differential field be thought of as actually consisting of functions?

Tags: fields, differential-algebra

*Previously [asked and bountied at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636727/can-every-not-too-big-differential-field-be-thought-of-as-actually-consisting) without success:*

Let $\sim$ denote the "no-disagreement" relation between partial functions: $f\sim g$ iff there is no $x$ such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are each defined and are distinct. For a  [differential field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra#Differential_field) $\mathcal{K}=(K;0,1,+,\cdot,\partial)$, let $C(\mathcal{K})=\{f\in K: \partial f=0\}$ be the constant subfield.

Say that a differential field $\mathcal{K}$ is **fully concrete** iff there is some way to assign, to each $\alpha\in K$, a partial function $\pi_\alpha:C(\mathcal{K})\rightarrow C(\mathcal{K})$ such that:

- For $\gamma\in C(\mathcal{K})$, $\pi_\gamma$ is the constant function $\lambda x. \gamma$.
- $\pi$ is injective-up-to-$\sim$, in the sense that $\pi_\alpha\not\sim\pi_\beta$ whenever $\alpha\not=\beta$.
- $\mathcal{K}$ is closed-up-to-$\sim$ under composition, in the sense that for each $\alpha,\beta\in K$ there is a unique $\gamma\in K$ such that $\pi_\gamma\sim\pi_\alpha\circ\pi_\beta$. (Since the functions involved are partial, this falls short of $\pi_\gamma=\pi_\alpha\circ\pi_\beta$.) I'll write "$\alpha\circ\beta$" for this unique $\gamma$.
- The field operations commute-up-to-$\sim$ with $\pi$, in the sense that $$\lambda x.\pi_{\alpha\star\beta}(x)\sim\lambda x.[\pi_\alpha(x)\star\pi_\beta(x)]$$ for $\star\in\{+,\cdot\}$.
- The chain rule holds, in the sense that $\partial(\alpha\circ\beta)=[(\partial\alpha)\circ\beta]\cdot\partial\beta$.

Finally, say that a differential field is **concrete** iff it is a sub-differential field of a fully concrete differential field with the same constant subfield. (To motivate concreteness as opposed to full concreteness, consider the example - pointed out to me by Qiaochu Yuan - of $\mathbb{C}(f)$ equipped with the obvious derivation satisfying $\partial(f)=f$. Clearly this differential field should be concrete via $f\mapsto \lambda x.e^x$, but we don't have closure under composition within $\mathbb{C}(f)$ itself.)

Concreteness seems like a natural property to consider for differential fields, but I haven't run into it before (I'm very new to differential fields though) and it's not obvious to me how common or rare it is. To get things started:

> Suppose $\mathcal{K}$ is a differential field with the same cardinality as its constant subfield. Must $\mathcal{K}$ be concrete?

I'm also generally interested in any sources about concreteness, or any variant thereof - generally, when can a differential field be "faithfully" thought of as consisting of partial functions over its constant subfield?

---

EDIT: The most relevant result I've found so far is the embedding theorem from [Singer's *The model theory of ordered differential fields*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2271951.pdf?refreqid=fastly-default%3A1c056e3600f2390a49f8fa79531f9e70&ab_segments=&origin=&initiator=&acceptTC=1). However, it is at least in statement more specific than what I'm looking for, and it's not clear to me that the argument there can be applied to this more general question.